# why 'os' appears as submodule of my package

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, pypi

Importing my package shows 'os' as submodule of my package.
Example:
Suppose I have a package with the following structure:

```
-- setup.py
-- my_package
  |-- __init__.py
  |-- example.py
```

`example.py` could be:

```
import os

def helloWorld():
    print('Hello World')
```

The package is installed using `python setup.py install`.

When further using `import my_package` I find `my_package.example.os`. How can I avoid 'os' from appearing as submodule?

I use python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but it's normal and desired.

The same way `import mypackage` gives you access to `mypackage.example.helloWorld`, you get access to `mypackage.example.os`, because both are in the main namespace of `mypackage.example` (you can use `os` within `helloWorld`, for example).

Note that this does not mean that `os` is included in your package.